# Unique visitors from Google Analytics

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics, seo

is there a way to display on each page/post in WordPress counter with unique visitors from Google Analytics?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You should look out the Google Analytics API, you have PHP example in the doc

https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api#query_profile

You also have a wordpress plugin who can help you to achieve that

https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-analytics-post-pageviews/